# Limits on NLME regression?

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

I am currently using `nlme` to perform mixed-effects regression.

I would like to perform constrained  optimization by providing upper and lower bounds to the parameters within the call to `nlme`.

Is this possible?

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/nlme/html/intervals.lme.html

Comment: That provides the confidence intervals on the calculated coefficients, but does not provide the ability to limit the coefficients during the regression.

Comment: What do you mean by *ability to limit the coefficients during the regression*.

Comment: See `lower` and `upper` in [nlminb](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/nlminb.html)

Comment: Not easily (perhaps), see [this old help thread](http://www.math.yorku.ca/Who/Faculty/Monette/pub/lme/0102.html), but the answer is from one of the authors of `nlme`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define your upper bounds as a vector `upper_bounds` of the same length as the vector passed to the `start` argument of `nlme`, then you can set the upper bounds via `nlmeControl()`:

```
nlme(..., control = nlmeControl(opt = "nlminb", upper = upper_bounds))
```

This may not have been possible when the question was asked but it works in `nlme` version 3.1.137.

Comment: Putting bounds on the `nlminb` optimization will not constrain on your fixed effects estimates since these are estimated in another step of the algorithm

Answer (score 2):

Here are two easy ways, without messing with nlme parameters: 1) fit a set of models on your boundaries and choose the model with the best fit, and 2) use a transformed version of your parameter that maps the reals to your desired interval.

Answer (score 1):

You can have upper and lower bounds for estimates in a mixed-effects regression in R. R has a rich resource on mixed model analysis. [This](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Fox-Companion/appendix-mixed-models.pdf) link explains mixed-model concepts as well as provides R code step by step using `nlme`.

You may also refer to [this](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/nlsList-nlme-control-of-min-and-max-parameter-bounds-td1746242.html) post for constrained optimization using `nlme`.

Comment: They are there in some form. See page-3 for `nlme`. The function for estimating the model is `lme`.

Comment: I deleted my earlier comment because I could find `nlme`, but I still don't see anything about limit, upper, or lower -- which are keywords for the `nlminb` the algorithm used in the `nlme` optimization. I have read all of the `nlme` and related documents.